# How do I add a delay for hovering an element in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an element:

```
<div (mouseenter)="enter()" (mouseleave)="leave()">Title</div>
```

TS:

```
onHover = false;

enter() {
    this.onHover = true;
    // doing some other stuff...
}

leave() {
    this.onHover = false;
    // doing some other stuff...
}
```

I want to add 2 seconds delay to **mouseenter** event like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835774/how-do-i-add-a-delay-for-hovering-an-element-in-angularjs). If user hovers >= 2 seconds on that element, I want to trigger mouseenter, not before. I tried **setTimeout**, but it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I see not setTimeout here,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised that I forgot to add **clearTimeout**. I've solved it like this:

```
onHover = false;
to;

enter() {
    this.to = setTimeout(() => {
        this.onHover = true;
        // doing some other stuff...
    }, 2000);
}

leave() {
    clearTimeout(this.to);
    this.onHover = false;
    // doing some other stuff...
}
```